# Upload website to server

Tags: web

I'm a developing a website and the client has decided to provide they're own hosting. They've purchased a mac mini, this is all they require for the scope of the project. They've given me to full access to the server via a remote desktop connection. I'm not too great on this side of things. I'm sure there's a lot of required information I'm not providing for a full answer but any help? I'm not really sure what I'm suppose to be doing with this.

Answer (score 0):

Is your website static (no server side language / database)?
Is it for internet or intranet?
The generic answer would be telling you to enable OS X Apache server, configure a virtual host, edit httpd.conf configuration, configure the static ip, configure the DNS servers, etc, etc, etc. Quite a lot of steps (but most are simple).
Take a look at this serie of articles: http://oreilly.com/pub/ct/49